# Toolchain integration in CDT(Build artifact extension does not get changed)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I have integrating code sourcery tool-chain with CDT for making arm build.
When I create a new project from eclipse by choosing codesourcery toolchain type project, I am able to generate the binary and everything works as per the expectation.

But when I change the toolchain from toolchain editor to any other toolchain and come back to my toolchain, Build Artifact extension does not get changed to expected value.

Ex.
1. Create the project using code-sourcery toolchain(shared library)
2. Now the build artifact extension is "so"
3. I am able to build it and .so is generated
4. Change the toolchain to any other toolchain (lets say VC++), It does not update the extension to dll(VC++ does not support .so)

The other way around also does not work
1. Create the project using VC++(shared lib, extension=dll)
2. Change the toolchain to code sourcery, extension is still .dll(this tool chain does not support .dll)

Any suggestion, where the problem could be? is it a CDT bug?

Thanks,
Vikas